# TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key. in Keras Surgeon

Tags: keras, tf.keras, vgg-net, pruning

I'm using Kerassurgeon module for pruning.I encountered this error while i'm working with VGG-16 in google colab.It works fine for other models.Can someone help me fix this.

```
---> 17   model_new = surgeon.operate()<br>
     18   return model_new

>>/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerassurgeon/surgeon.py in operate(self)
    152             sub_output_nodes = utils.get_node_inbound_nodes(node)
    153             outputs, output_masks = self._rebuild_graph(self.model.inputs,
--> 154                                                         sub_output_nodes)
    155 
    156             # Perform surgery at this node

>>/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerassurgeon/surgeon.py in _rebuild_graph(self, graph_inputs, output_nodes, graph_input_masks)
    264         # Call the recursive _rebuild_rec method to rebuild the submodel up to
    265         # each output layer
--> 266         outputs, output_masks = zip(*[_rebuild_rec(n) for n in output_nodes])
    267         return outputs, output_masks
    268 

>>/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerassurgeon/surgeon.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    264         # Call the recursive _rebuild_rec method to rebuild the submodel up to
    265         # each output layer
--> 266         outputs, output_masks = zip(*[_rebuild_rec(n) for n in output_nodes])
    267         return outputs, output_masks
    268 

>>/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerassurgeon/surgeon.py in _rebuild_rec(node)
    216             # Check for replaced tensors before any other checks:
    217             # these are created by the surgery methods.
--> 218             if node_output in self._replace_tensors.keys():
    219                 logging.debug('bottomed out at replaced output: {0}'.format(
    220                     node_output))

>>/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __hash__(self)
    724     if (Tensor._USE_EQUALITY and executing_eagerly_outside_functions() and
    725         (g is None or g.building_function)):
--> 726       raise TypeError("Tensor is unhashable. "
    727                       "Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.")
    728     else:

**TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.**
```

Comment: It will be helpful to get at least a snippet of code that is responsible for the error you post.

Comment: If you got to solve the issue please let us know, I am stuck at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error. this is due to change of versions.Use Kerassurgeon instead of tfkerassurgeon.

Use the following versions

```
tf 1.x , keras > 2.2 , kerassurgeon
```

Answer (score 14):

I have solved a similar problem when I try the [Deep learning example with GradientExplainer](https://github.com/slundberg/shap). This is caused by version incompatibility.
Adding the code below may be helpful:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

tf version is 2.3.1
kerase version is 2.4.0
Shap version is 0.36

Answer (score 2):

Please try the code below:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

1.*compat* allows you to write code that works both in TensorFlow 1. x and 2 and should
solve any errors based on the *version import*.

2.*eager_execution* is an interface which allows for operations as soon as it is called
from Python. Turning it on allows for Tensorflow to be more intuitive.

3.But then why should *eager_execution* be disabled?
->*eager_execution* is slower than *graph_execution*. It runs operations line-by-line
which renders the potential acceleration oppurtunities useless.

4.Run **tf.executing_eagerly()** to check is *eager_execution* is on or off.

Hopefully this helps in allaying your errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem, I have solved it using next lines:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the similar problem when I try to run yolo3 model.  I have solved with:
`import tensorflow as tf`
`tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()`

seems it is caused by the version incompatibility when tensorflow  updated fron V1.x to V2.x

Hope it helps.